# Can one signal that a target has not been rebuilt, from its recipe?

Tags: gnu-make

In GNU make, is there any way to detect or forcibly signal that a (phony) target hasn't resulted in any rebuild action even though its recipe has been triggered?

What I want is a recursive make call, like:

```
target: subtarget
        # recipe

.PHONY: subtarget
subtarget:
        $(MAKE) -C subdir something
```

Of course it's quite possible that the recursive `make` call finds there's nothing to make for `something`. But by that time, since the recipe for `subtarget` has been started, the recipe for `target` will also always be executed. Is there any way to avoid this?

(I have seen that the GNU manual advises against using phony targets as prerequisites, but that in itself seems quite a restriction of their usefulness.)

Seems to me this should be a common problem, but I've not found any references. Any help is much appreciated.

ADDED: in the context where I want to use this, I don't necessarily know what `something` builds exactly: it, too, might be a phony target that eventually creates a bunch of `*.xyz` files that I do not know or want to know at this level (separation of concerns and all that). Otherwise it would be easy to add `subdir/something` as a prerequisite to `subtarget`.

Comment: Where's a mad scientist when you need one... maybe this is not so common a problem. Recursive make, PHONY targets as prerequisites, it smells icky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to signal make to not run a target.  Make looks *only* at modification times to tell when to rebuild something.

However, make will not rebuild a target if none of its prerequisites are newer than it is, even if the recipe for that prerequisite was invoked.

So, in your situation you need to remove the `.PHONY`, then have `target` depend on `something`, not on some phony rule `subtarget`.  Finally you have to ensure that subtarget itself is always run.  A simple way is with the old-school `FORCE` method (note this is not special to `make`; naming it `FORCE` is just a convention).  Something like this:

```
target: something
        # recipe

something: FORCE
        $(MAKE) -C subdir $@

FORCE: ;
```

Now `something` is always remade (so the sub-make always runs), but `target` will only be remade if `something` actually changes its timestamp.

Comment: Equivalently, you could have `something` depend on a `.PHONY` target.  But `something` _itself_ cannot be a `.PHONY` target.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is clear (the first word says it all ;-)) but your proposed alternative solves the wrong aspect of the problem: I don't necessarily _want_ `something` to be re-invoked all the time, but I would like the recipe of `target` _not_ to be invoked unless necessary. I've added a paragraph to my question to describe the context a bit better.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, maybe I can create a representative "real" (i.e., non-phony) target for `subdir/something` just for the purpose of this `make` step. Then the recursively called `make` call can add the `*.xyz` files as prerequisites there, invisibly to the outer `make`. Kind of a dedicated return value in the form of a file whose only interesting attribute is its modification time, not its content. Does that make sense?

Comment: I understood what you meant.  In the parent makefile, the `something` rule is just a placeholder to invoke the sub-make.  It's the sub-make that will actually decide whether `something` is rebuilt or not.  Thus you always want to run the `something` rule in the parent makefile, so the sub-make is always run.  It may or may not do anything, but until the sub-make runs you don't know.  Once that is decided, and the sub-make exits, then the parent can make a decision.  In your question you made it sound like the result of the sub-make was a single target, `something`.  If not, more is needed.

Comment: If the sub-make is generating more than one target file, not just the single `something`, then you need to use a sentinel file or stamp file.  Have every target in the sub-make that you want to cause the parent make's `target` to rebuild, touch a stamp file (`touch .subdir.update` or whatever) as part of its recipe.  Then in the parent makefile, instead of `target` depending on `something`, have it depend in `subdir/.subdir.update`.  All else is the same as in my answer above.

Comment: Right; sentinel file, sounds good - indeed, I think this solution coincides with what I had been thinking of, "sentinel file" == "return value of the sub-make". Thanks a lot. I accepted your answer, but maybe you can enrich it by putting the above suggestion in there?